# Class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0

Tags: java, macos, java-8, java-11, javac

I am trying to run some code and am receiving the following error:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
/Users/sahil/Downloads/ptltrader-1.6.0/src/main/java/com/pairtradinglab/ptltrader/model/validator/MarginPercents.java:23: error: cannot access IStatus
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus;
                               ^
  bad class file: /Users/sahil/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.equinox.common/3.17.0/a86196c9ec6239dd479ea4a04121a5f0cf3343a8/org.eclipse.equinox.common-3.17.0.jar(org/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus.class)
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I understand that this means the code is running in Java 11 and needs to run in Java 8, but I don't know why it appears that everything is in Java 8. Any help would be appreciated.

**Specs:**

MacOS Big Sur v11.6.8

Java "Version 8 Update 351"

Gradle v7.6

Homebrew v3.6.16

**In code:**

java v1.8.0

javac v1.8.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "but I don't know why it appears that everything is in Java 8." **How do you know? What concrete steps did you take** in order to verify this?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for the warm welcome. In regards to what I've done to verify everything is in Java 8, I've checked the version running on my Mac (8), and the versions used in my code (1.8.0). When running `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`, I notice that there is a version 17.0.5 installed. Should I attempt to uninstall this? What other steps can I do to verify the Java 8 status? Thank you.

Comment: Post details as edits to your Question, not Comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the class `IStatus` which you're referencing was compiled for Java 11 which is newer than your Java version (8) so the solution is to update your JDK or find a version of your library for Java 8.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I believe this source says that I'm running in Java 11 (55), but the class was compiled for/should be running Java 8 (52): https://devcases.com/java/how-to-check-java-version-used-to-compile-a-class/

Comment: Java is backward compatible which means that a given version of it can load classes compiled for earlier versions but not for later versions; so a Java 11 VM can load a class compiled for Java 8. That website mentions a "library with a higher supported version of Java" which—as in your case—is 11 while it is being used by a Java 8 compiler—which does not work.

Comment: Upgrading to Java 11 worked! I have another error but regarding this problem, my question was answered. Thank you and happy holidays!